# Xamarin Android Firebase Database, Cs1503 Error, Cannot convert from a class object to java.lang.object

Tags: android, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

```
namespace RatingForBoth.Droid.Model
{
    public class ProductModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Expertise { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public string Rate { get; set; }
        public string NumOfRate { get; set; }

        public ProductModel(string pName, string pExp, string pTag, string pRate, string pNumOfRate)
        {
            Name = pName;
            Expertise = pExp;
            Tag = pTag;
            Rate = pRate;
            NumOfRate = pNumOfRate;
        }

        public ProductModel() { }

        // to show the category name in the textview from the listview
        public override string ToString()
        {
            // Format your product name here as you want it to be displayed.
            return $"{Name}";
        }
    }
}
```

this is the model.

```
DatabaseReference fbRef;

        //Android depency dosyamız. İnterface olarak shared da tanımladığımız interface IFBHelper a bağlı. 
        public void ConnectFirebase()
        {
            fbRef = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance("https://ratingforboth.firebaseio.com/").Reference;

        }

        public void SendProduct(string pName, string pExp, string pTag)
        {
            ProductModel p = new ProductModel(pName, pExp, pTag, "0", "0");
            fbRef.Child("Products").Push().SetValueAsync(p);     // error is here for "p" variable. cs1503 cannot convert productmodel to java.lang.object

        }
```

This is local android class has dependency.

In sendproduct method, error occurs. I am using Xamarin.Firebase.Database nuget package from XAMARIN inc. I see some possible solutions, but don't understand anything. I have stuck here for one day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution after deep research.

You need to implement model class to Java.lang.object.

Error is gone wih this correction. But then another error comes.

Sending data as with this model, doesnt work. Then i add hashmap method to this model class. And changed model data to hashmap. And success. But....

When retrieving data, i took data but couldnt send to main form app. Because main form app doesnt accept this model because of implementing to java.lang.object.

So, i need to changed this model to something else. But i tired of all of these. I think i will drop off firebase in xamarin.

There is lack of information, no tutorial, no info, no help on internet.

**Edit:**
Use this code to convert

https://gist.github.com/Cheesebaron/9876783